# How to get lat n lng center point of map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-camera

I am building an android application where user is getting latLng by long touching in Google map.

Here is the code:

```
    public class MainActivitytut extends FragmentActivity{

GoogleMap googleMap;
MarkerOptions markerOptions;
LatLng latLng;
private TextView myAddress;
String lat;
TextView txtmapinfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maintut);



    //onBackPressed();
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    // Getting a reference to the map
        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();

        // Setting a click event handler for the map
        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {               

                // Getting the Latitude and Longitude of the touched location
                latLng = arg0;
                lat = latLng.toString();
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lat,
        //             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //  getMyLocationAddress();
                // Clears the previously touched position
                googleMap.clear();

                // Animating to the touched position                                
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));             

                // Creating a marker
                markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                // Setting the position for the marker
                markerOptions.position(latLng);                     

                // Placing a marker on the touched position
                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                // Adding Marker on the touched location with address
                new ReverseGeocodingTask(getBaseContext()).execute(latLng);             

            }
        });      

  }


protected void putExtra(String string, CharSequence text) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is
    // present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}
}
```

I had used `lat = map.getCameraPosition().target;` and when I toast the value of lat, it is toasting 0.0

What I need is that when on swiping the map the latlng change and toast.

Answer (score 1):

Wait until the map has loaded and then call getCameraPosition:

```
mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapLoaded() {
        LatLng pos = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
        Log.e("", "Pos: " + pos.toString());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos));
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please tell how to set an mark with this center cameraposition please help me. I am new to android.

Comment: @Sonam "My app is crushing" is not helpful at all. Post the error you are getting in your question.

Comment: this is the error in my logcat - 11-20 19:49:15.251: E/NativeCrypto(23310): ssl=0x5c413010 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x5e978a40 arg=0x0

Comment: @Sonam I said in your question. I can't read the error message from a comment.

Comment: I had copy past the error that was show in my logcat

Comment: @Sonam sorry if you don't understand me, I can't help you.

Comment: i think this is showing because I am not using it properly as I dont know how to set your ans comment after map is loaded.

Comment: can you please tell me how to add your code after map is loaded